# Change font color for Admin account in socialengine

Tags: php, css, admin, socialengine

This is probably a stupid simple question, but I'm not very code savvy. I moderate a forum on socialengine and I want the admin account font color to be in red, so users know who the admin is. Is there a way to do that in the admin panel area?

this is the furthest I've gotten from googling and research, but I'm not sure where to put this piece of code:

```
<?php if($this->viewer()->getIdentity() == '1'){ ?>
<style>***change to red***</style>
```

I want the h2 header to be in red as well as the link in "popular members" where the admin account shows up. How can I achieve this? I'm hoping there is a way in the admin area to do it, just can't seem to find it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .is-admin {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<h2 <?php echo ($this->viewer()->getIdentity() == '1' ? 'class="is-admin"' : '');?>>Username</h2>
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know where to put that html/php line of code? I'm searching throughout the site directory and can't seem to find where that header is generated :/ social engine confuses me

Comment: I am sorry, I don't. Maybe their theme-starter-kit helps you: http://blog.socialengine.com/2012/10/25/socialengine-themes-kit-released/?_ga=1.19650493.463537406.1456429049